# In MongoDB, why is read concern "available" default option for secondaries in non causally consistent sessions?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-replication, sharding

I am confused about how causal consistency affects the decision of choosing between read-concern "local" vs "available".

Why read-concern "available" is default for secondaries when it is a non causally consistent session ?

I understand how "available" behaves for sharded clusters vs "local" behaves for unsharded collections.

I just cannot make the connection based on reading the documents.

I would really appreciate if someone helped me bridge. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a summary of read concern levels in terms of a sharded cluster:

- **majority**: only returns data that was written to the majority of voting nodes and will not be rolled back.
- **local**: returns data on the local node, but with orphaned documents filtered out. This requires the node to communicate with the shard's primary (if this read is on a secondary), or the config server to service the read. In a degraded sharded cluster, this read may stall indefinitely. This is not an issue for an unsharded collection, though. Possible to return data that could be rolled back.
- **available**: returns whatever data that is available. This is to allow read availability as a priority over correctness. Possible to return data that could be rolled back. See [Read Concern "available"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-available/)

Shard secondaries default to "available" read concern to maintain behaviour compatibility with MongoDB 3.4 (see [SERVER-31032](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31032))

Causal consistency can provide different guarantees depending on the read & write concern used (see [Causal Consistency and Read and Write Concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/index.html) for an exhaustive detail), where a balance between read own writes, monotonic reads, monotonic writes, and writes follow reads can be achieved by using different levels of read & write concerns.

Since causal consistency provides a semblance of guarantee of data integrity, it is not compatible with "available" read concern, since "available" is meant to provide no guarantee regarding integrity, but to emphasize availability instead.

Comment: Could you please drop a link to read more about the local concern case for the degraded cluster? " In a degraded sharded cluster, this read may stall indefinitely". Thx.

Comment: Not sure what "more" you still need on that statement. A read with "local" has to get the latest meta data to filter orphaned docs, which obviously takes time. No "more" is needed on this.